# How to render YouTube videos as a texture in A-Frame?

Tags: webvr, aframe

I want to take a YouTube url, and put it into an A-Frame scene as a video texture. Like `<a-video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">`. Is this possible for https://aframe.io?

Comment: what is an `<a-video>` element?

Comment: It's part of A-Frame (https://aframe.io), a WebVR framework.

I'm just asking common questions and self-answering them to share knowledge. We just got the `aframe` tag so in the future, I'll limit it to that tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some manual effort, you could either:

- Proxy YouTube videos as a texture like https://github.com/cvan/webvr360 / https://www.dropbox.com/s/298brayuh24et13/webvr360.mp4?dl=0
- Download them locally to serve with a service.

Note that these are probably against their terms of service.